# How to match rows in the same table across schemas by using foreign key restraints

Tags: sql, postgresql

Postgres version info: "PostgreSQL 9.1.14 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4), 64-bit"

I have a table T with columns Id, Field1, Field2 in two different schemas (though that's not important), S and S'. The table T has a reference table F that contains the fields Id, Field1 with Id being a foreign key to table T.

```
CREATE TABLE S.T
(
  Id character varying(36) NOT NULL,
  FieldA character varying(32) NOT NULL,
  FieldB  character varying(250),
  CONSTRAINT pk_T PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)

CREATE TABLE S.F
(
  Id character varying(36) NOT NULL,
  Field1 character varying(36) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_F PRIMARY KEY (Id, Field1),
  CONSTRAINT fk_F_T FOREIGN KEY (Id)
      REFERENCES S.T(Id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Similarly in schema S' we have tables T' and F'. Note that there is a 1..n relationship between T and F, that is, multiple rows in F with the same Id.

I want to create a query that will match rows between T and T' based on the Field1 values in F.

```
Example in Schema S:
T.Id | T.FieldA | T.FieldB      F.Id | F.Field1
--------------------------      ---------------
1    | A        | B             1    | XYZ
2    | C        | D             1    | WVU 
                                2    | STR
                                2    | PQR

Example in Schema S':
T'.Id | T'.FieldA | T'.FieldB      F'.Id | F'.Field1
--------------------------      ---------------
1'    | A'        | B'             1'    | XYZ
2'    | C'        | D'             1'    | WVU 
                                   2'    | STR
                                   2'    | PQR
```

How do I make a query matches row 1 from T with row 1' from T' since they have the same foreign key info XYZ and WVU, and similarly row 2 from T with row 2' from T'? In other words rows are uniquely defined by their matching rows in F.

Of course, they query isn't as simple as the above: Rows are matched between T and T' by the info in F (and F', respectively) and T.FieldA and then with a successful match I will need to update T'.FieldB.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: horrible names those: `s'`,`Id` doe you really want examples cluttered with double quotes?

Comment: is it signifigant that both `1` rows of `f` match both `1'` rows of `f'` ? is one matching row enough, are non-matching rows significant?  if there was another tow in `f` with `(1,'FOO')` would row `1` of `t` still match row `1'` of `t'` ?

Comment: No. If F had another row associated with 1 that wasn't in F' then we shouldn't get a match between row 1 of T and row 1' of T'.

Comment: that makes it much harder a means is needed to combine the several rows in f into a single row in a way that always selects the rows in the same order.

Comment: you may find thise useful: `select id,a,b,array_agg(field1) from (select a.t.id,a.t.a,a.t.b,a.f.field1 from a.t join a.f using (id) order by a.t.id,a.f.field1) as aa group by id,a,b;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your example data - I have renamed some things to make life easier.

```
create schema a; create schema b;
create table a.t (id int primary key ,a text,b text);
insert into a.t values(1,'A','B'),(2,'C','D');
create table a.f (id int references a.t(id),field1 text);
insert into a.f values (1,'XYZ'),(1,'WVU'),(2,'STR'),(2,'PQR');
create table b.t (id int primary key ,a text,b text);
insert into b.t values(11,'A''','B'''),(22,'C''','D''');
create table b.f (id int references b.t(id),field1 text);
insert into b.f values (11,'XYZ'),(11,'WVU'),(22,'STR'),(22,'PQR');
```

the join:

```
SELECT * FROM a.t 
  JOIN a.f ON a.t.id = a.f.id
  JOIN b.f ON a.f.field1 = b.f.field1 
  JOIN b.t ON b.t.id = b.f.id
```

an update?:

```
UPDATE b.t 
  SET b=b.t.b||'('||a.t.id||')'
  FROM a.f 
    JOIN b.f ON a.f.field1 = b.f.field1 
    JOIN a.t ON a.t.id = a.f.id 
  WHERE b.t.id = b.f.id
;
```

the cleanup

```
drop schema a cascade;drop schema b cascade;
```

Comment: I'm thinking that might be wrong ? you want to combine both rows of table t ?

Comment: I get what you mean with the ' now - serves me right for trying to be mathematical. Sorry about that.

Comment: One idea was to use something like string_agg to create a "business key" made up of the Field1 strings concatenated, together with the anything else to generate a hashcode of the row - the business key.

Comment: yes, but order will be significant, so it must be costrained when biulding the key, else when the tables get large enough for hash join to be used the order will come out random. and then the join won't work...

Comment: maybe hash the f.field1 (eg: use md5) and then use a bitwise XOR to aggregate the hashes. xor is commutative so it will be immune to row-order issues.

Comment: Indeed a "natural" ordering has be enforced on F and F'. Mmmm.